# What is the difference between != null and !== null?

Tags: javascript

Sorry for what I'm sure had have been asked in the past, but it's very hard to search for a question like this. "!=" and "!==" are not exactly search friendly. If anyone knows a duplicate question you can point me to it.

What is the difference between doing `myVar != null` and `myVar !== null`?
I know that `!=` is `not equal` and `!==` is `not equal value or not equal type`, but when comparing to null is there ever a case where they would return different results? Is one better to use than the other?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript?rq=1

Comment: I searched for "javascript scrict inequality vs inequality" and found stuff, but knowing the name of things can be hard. I have no idea how people search for `? :` the first time they see `x = y ? z :w;`

Comment: look here for detailed explanation: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/types%20%26%20grammar/ch4.md

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The answer to the specific question about whether there's ever a case where `!=` and `!==` comparisons involving `null` get different answers is **yes**:

```
undefined != null  // false
undefined == null  // true

undefined === null // false
undefined !== null // true
```

The rules for `==` and `!=` explicitly include a clause that stipulates that `null` and `undefined` are the same.

Personally — that is, in my code — that fact is a reason for using `!=` (or `==`) when checking for `null` in cases where `undefined` should be treated the same way (which is a pretty common situation).

Comment: Also, Lodash's [isNil](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#isNil) function checks whether the given value is 'nullish' (that is `null` or `undefined`) and behind the scenes does exactly that: checks if the given value `== null`.