# Auth Context has some issues with types

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, async-await, supabase

My code doesn't work, although it was made using [this tutorial (link to exact file with AuthContext)](https://github.com/dom-the-dev/movie-tinder-YouTube/blob/main/src/auth.js). This snippet in particular is a part of Auth Context. The only difference is that I code in typescript instead of JS. Tell me whether you need anything else to help me solve my issue.

```
useEffect(() => {
        const user = supabase.auth.getUser().user;
        setCurrentUser(user)

        const auth = supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange((event, session) => {
            if (event === 'SIGNED_IN') {
                setCurrentUser(session.user)
            }

            if (event === 'SIGNED_OUT') {
                setCurrentUser(null)
            }
        })

        return () => auth.data.unsubscribe()

    }, [])
```

Errors:

```
ERROR in src/contexts/AuthContext.tsx:76:46
TS2339: Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Promise<UserResponse>'.
    74 |
    75 |     useEffect(() => {
  > 76 |         const user = supabase.auth.getUser().user;
       |                                              ^^^^
    77 |         setCurrentUser(user)
    78 |
    79 |         const auth = supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange((event, session) => {

ERROR in src/contexts/AuthContext.tsx:81:32
TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.
    79 |         const auth = supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange((event, session) => {
    80 |             if (event === 'SIGNED_IN') {
  > 81 |                 setCurrentUser(session.user)
       |                                ^^^^^^^
    82 |             }
    83 |
    84 |             if (event === 'SIGNED_OUT') {

ERROR in src/contexts/AuthContext.tsx:81:32
TS2345: Argument of type 'User' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<undefined>'.
  Type 'User' provides no match for the signature '(prevState: undefined): undefined'.
    79 |         const auth = supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange((event, session) => {
    80 |             if (event === 'SIGNED_IN') {
  > 81 |                 setCurrentUser(session.user)
       |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    82 |             }
    83 |
    84 |             if (event === 'SIGNED_OUT') {

ERROR in src/contexts/AuthContext.tsx:85:32
TS2345: Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<undefined>'.
    83 |
    84 |             if (event === 'SIGNED_OUT') {
  > 85 |                 setCurrentUser(null)
       |                                ^^^^
    86 |             }
    87 |         })
    88 |

ERROR in src/contexts/AuthContext.tsx:89:32
TS2339: Property 'unsubscribe' does not exist on type '{ subscription: Subscription; }'.
    87 |         })
    88 |
  > 89 |         return () => auth.data.unsubscribe()
       |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^
    90 |
    91 |     }, [])
    92 |
```

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: *My code doesn't work* and *issues* are meaningless problem statements. Please [edit] your post to provide information describing the problem you're having with the code you've posted, and to ask a **specific question** related to that code.

Answer (score 1):

**Supabase v@2.0.0+**

The available auth functions and their return types have changed slightly. They no longer offers the `supabase.auth.user()` function and only offer the promisable `supabase.auth.getUser()`. The return type of getUser is

```
export type UserResponse =
  | {
      data: {
        user: User
      }
      error: null
    }
  | {
      data: {
        user: null
      }
      error: AuthError
    }
```

I believe object deconstructing is also more readable so

```js
const { data: { user } = await supabase.auth.getUser()
```

would be preferred.

This also address the return problem of `onAuthStateChange()`, return type of

```
{
  data: { subscription: Subscription }
}
```

So your code would change to

```js
const { data: { subscription }} = supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange(callback);
```

**Supabase v@1.0.0+**
Supbase offers two functions retrieving the user, `.user().` and `.getUser()`. `.user()` fetches the user from localStorage, which means it is a non-Promise function. `.getUser()` fetches the user from the server using a jwt, and thus is a Promise. In the tutorial they use `.user()` function, which why there is no await. In your code you use the `.getUser()` function. To continue to user the `.getUser()` function in the useEffect, you would have to call  it inside async function

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchUser = async() => {
    const { user } = await supabase.auth.getUser();
    setCurrentUser(user);
  }
  fetchUser();
},[])
```

**useState types**
To address the useState errors, you have to pass a type to your useState() function when the type of the state will be of a different type of the defaultValue you pass to it.
`const [str, setStr] = useState('');` infers the variable to be a string, while `const [idk, setIdk] = useState(null)` only infers the variable to be undefined, that's why it's throwing errors when you try to set currentUser to a variable of type User or null.

The way to fix this would be to pass the User type to useState

```js
import { User } from '@supabase/supabase-js';

const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState<User | null>(null);
```

**Nullish checks**
To address the errors of 'Object could be null', all you have to do is add a nullish check, either in the form of an if/else statement

```
if(user) or if(user !== null) {
  setCurrentUser(user)
}
```

or adding a nullish variable check, `

```
const user = session?.user;
```

There is a slight difference between !user or user !== null, with the latter being less inclusive. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38977829/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-null)

The docs for both [supabase](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript) and [typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/) are great resources

If you don't have a particular need to create your own auth system for supabase, I would recommend [supabase-auth-helpers](https://github.com/supabase/auth-helpers).